# Why does creating Apache wildcard subdomain and IP create an infinite redirect?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have Apache configure with several IP addresses:

```
Listen 111.111.111.111:80
Listen 111.111.111.111:443

Listen 222.222.222.222:80
Listen 222.222.222.222:443

Listen 333.333.333.333:80
Listen 333.333.333.333:443
```

(IPs are fake)

I have several VirtualHosts, one of which is a wildcard subdomain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName *.example1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example1-wc/docs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example1/docs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example2/docs
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine. Requests to www.example1.com are served under the example1 docroot, requests for example.example1.com are served under the example1-wc docroot and www.example2.com for example2 docroot.

I can change www.example2.com to use a specific IP without any problems however if I change the wildcard vhost *.example1.com to a specific IP:

```
<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80>
        ServerName *.example1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example1-wc/docs
</VirtualHost>
```

Then requests to www.example1.com create an infinite redirect loop on itself. This happens regardless of whether I use:

```
<VirtualHost 222.222.222.222:80>
        ServerName www.example1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example1/docs
</VirtualHost>
```

or

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example1/docs
</VirtualHost>
```

Why is this happening and how can I get each virtualhost on its own IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the root of your problem, but you should probably have the directives

```
NameVirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80
NameVirtualHost 222.222.222.222:80
NameVirtualHost 333.333.333.333:80
```

So the full configuration would have these directives in it:

```
Listen 111.111.111.111:80
NameVirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80
<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80>
    ServerName *.example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example1-wc/docs
</VirtualHost>

Listen 222.222.222.222:80
NameVirtualHost 222.222.222.222:80
<VirtualHost 222.222.222.222:80>
    ServerName www.example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example1/docs
</VirtualHost>

Listen 333.333.333.333:80
NameVirtualHost 333.333.333.333:80
<VirtualHost 333.333.333.333:80>
    ServerName www.example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example2/docs
</VirtualHost>
```

but this should not appear anywhere:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Here's some further reading, if you're interested: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html (good luck making sense of it ;-)

Comment: If you check the /var/log/httpd/error.log or similar apache will warn you about overlapping vhosts. You should follow Davids advice to correct that error

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but have you tried putting the definition for the wildcard subdomain **after** the www.example1.com definition?